# Problems with SCID

Tags: troubleshooting, menu, games

I've recently installed [scid](http://scid.sourceforge.net/) from ubuntu repositorys. I've met with 2 problems.
1) After install ; there isn't any shortcut made to run program; so I have to either run it from console or make my own shortcut.My experience so far was that shortcut is made during install.
2) I can't change width of gui after starting it; only length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
Menu options aren't "shortcuts", they are based on special `*.desktop` files (that also specify the document types it can open and other information about an application).  It seems like no *.desktop file is provided for `scid` (or it doesn't include the necessary info for a menu item) and as a result the menu system doesn't know about it.

If you want a menu item to be shown automaticly after the install, the best you can do is file a bug about it, and if you like to help you can also provide a working *.desktop file, or even better a debdiff, as an attachment to the bug report.  Also, asking the upstream author to provide a *.desktop file would help for the future.

(If you want to know how to create a *.desktop file and/or a debdiff, maybe ask separate questions about that; that way they will be easier to find in the future.)

2.
That sounds like a limitation that the program author is responsible for.  You can try to contact the author and ask if he/she wants to change it (or why not).

Comment: +1 for information regarding how to: Contribute to a fix and for having to file a bug about missing menu item and for mentioning possibly making a new question for `*.desktop` files. I would also probably mention that you can create Menu Items using `alacarte` or System -> Preferences -> Main Menu as a short term fix.